# Is this Cross-Site Scripting: DOM in dhtmlHistory.js

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer

I'm a newbie to js. One of the projects that I'm working on depends on **dhtmlHistory.js**. As I understand it, this js library is used to track history and bookmarking related functionalities, mainly in IE. Also, this library seems to be dead.

When I run a Fortify security scan, some vulnerabilities are found, e.g.:

```
var initialHash = this.getCurrentLocation();
if (this.isInternetExplorer()) {
         document.write("<iframe style='border: 0px; width: 1px; "
                               + "height: 1px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; "
                               + "right: 0px; visibility: visible;' "
                               + "name='DhtmlHistoryFrame' id='DhtmlHistoryFrame' "
                               + "src='blank.html?" + initialHash + "'>"
                               + "</iframe>");
         // wait 400 milliseconds between history
         // updates on IE, versus 200 on Firefox
         this.WAIT_TIME = 400;
      }
```

Here, the initialHash value that gets passed to the src parameter is not validated. Is this an actual risk?

Is there a way for me to find whether I can get rid of this library, since almost all modern browsers are capable of handling these features without the help of a 3rd party dependency at present?

Is there a mailing list where I can inquire about this question?

Updated:

```
getCurrentLocation: function() {
      var currentLocation = this.removeHash(window.location.hash);

      return currentLocation;
   },

removeHash: function(hashValue) {
      if (hashValue == null || hashValue == undefined)
         return null;
      else if (hashValue == "")
         return "";
      else if (hashValue.length == 1 && hashValue.charAt(0) == "#")
         return "";
      else if (hashValue.length > 1 && hashValue.charAt(0) == "#")
         return hashValue.substring(1);
      else
         return hashValue;     
   },
```

Comment: What does `this.getCurrentLocation()` return?

Comment: @SilverlightFox I've updated the question with that function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a risk.

If an attacker redirects a user to this page with a URL with the hash set like this:

```
https://example.com/page.htm#'/>+<img+src="x"+onerror="alert('xss')"+/>
```

the document write functionality will write this instead of just the IFrame:

```
<iframe style='border: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px;
 position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; visibility: visible;' 
name='DhtmlHistoryFrame' id='DhtmlHistoryFrame' 
src='blank.html?'/> <img src="x" onerror="alert('xss')" />'>
</iframe>
```

Boom - you have XSS.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I +1 the answer. Since this is a very old library. Do you have any idea about the dhtmlHistory.js?

Comment: HTML5 has `pushState` to replace saving history in URL hashes. [Info here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).